# Who Would Win? Insects/Animals vs Humans

Tags: warfare

How would humans defeat all animals and insects to ever exist?

I'm not looking for answers that ascribe human-level intelligence to animals or insects. This is real life, if insects are even close to smart enough to do that then every single person on Earth can deadlift 1000 pounds and run 20 miles in an hour. Be realistic. I know we could easily defeat all of the animals and insects (killing our planet in the process...) but I want to know HOW.

Comment: Flagged as inappropriate.  Welcome to Worldbuilding; please read the SE [Code of Conduct](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/conduct), notably: `No harassment.
This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.`

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the Worldbuilding SE is dedicated to providing detailed answers to specific questions you have while developing your fictional world. However, this seems, at best reading, to be a question concerning the development of a story. Writing your plot for you is outside the scope of this community.

Comment: Hello, @PeterGarfield, you are cordially invited to take the [tour] and to read up in the [help] about how we work and [ask] questions. Welcome to the site.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the book and TV show Zoo by James Patterson? It has a pretty similar plot to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal to eliminate all animals and insects, we will have to nuke the planet (a nuke every ~500 miles), and hide in shelters while killing whatever animals and insects sneak in there with us.

I hope you realize that bees pollinate most of fruit and vegetable crops. We will have very few foodstuffs left: see 3d paragraph here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_crop_plants_pollinated_by_bees

So yeah, soy burgers with just patty and bun, and banana for desert if you behaved yourself.

Comment: Even that probably wouldn't do the trick; lots of insects have no problem with radiation and wouldn't be as impacted even by the blast effects.

Comment: Who cares about the food? If you're going to die to murderous insects your immediate goal is survival and eliminating the threat. Nuking and hiding is a good strategy. All the insects and bacteria would die.

Comment: @PeterGarfield It's perfectly acceptable for you to post an answer to your own question if you think you have one that fits. You would of-course need to [edit] the question to fit within the rules as on-topic first.